# How to print the highest score on an external csv file

Tags: python, csv

I've created a little top trumps game and have a csv file that stores all the scores from previous games. How do I get it to print the highest score?

```py
field_names = ['player_name','score']

data = [{"player_name": player_name, 'score': score}]
with open("score.csv", "a") as csv_file:
    spreadsheet = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=field_names)
    spreadsheet.writerows(data)
with open('score.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    spreadsheet = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for row in spreadsheet:
        print(dict(row))
```

Comment: use pandas package..

Comment: @DataFace A very heavy dependency for such a simple problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a variable to remember the highest score, and initialize it to zero.

Read the csv file row by row.  If you see a score that is higher than the previous highest score, remember it as the new highest score.

At the end of the loop, print the highest score.

```
# initialize to a placeholder value
highest_score = 0

# read the csv file
with open('score.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    spreadsheet = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for row in spreadsheet:
        # convert the score column to an integer
        intscore = int(row['score'])

        # if this score is the highest so far, remember it
        if intscore > highest_score:
            highest_score = intscore

print(highest_score)
```

Comment: when I run the code I now get the error  File “/Users/Starwars/starwars.py”, line 67, in run
    intscore = int(row[‘score’])
KeyError: ‘score’

Comment: @zzzz-a The csv file must have some bad (or blank) rows.